# Spotfire : formula for calculated column based on the other columns

Tags: spotfire

I have an requirement to create an calculated column which calculates the difference of a value from previous row based on the value of other two columns.

FOR Example. Consider 4 columns as shown below. Col B and Col C has date values , Col A as some unique value and Col D will has some numerical values which will be used to calculate the required column, such that when Col B=Col C and corresponding value of Col D has to be taken and subtracted to Col D values until next time  Col B=Col C occurs.

IMAGE of Table (PS: I couldnt copy whole table in copiable way as format was going to messy)

[image]

I need Output like below : ie when the date values are equal ,[COL B]=[COL C] (ie 20-12-2016 15:40), then I have to corresponding value of COL D will be considered and subtracted with 138 ,until next similar occurrence happens.Next occurrence is for value 12-01-2017 15:40 , then it should be subtracted with 161 and this continues and its dynamic.

PLEASE NOTE : For the values before [COL B]=[COL C], those corresponding values should be same as COL D or if the Value of COL C is NULL or BLank then also its should be as COL D as highlighted in Green.

OUTPUT REQUIREMENT (As in Yellow)
[image]

I had used a code something as below in spotfire

```
if([COL B] is Not NULL,If([COL B]=[COL C],First[COL D] - [COL D]),[COL D])
```

, however since the value to be subtracted will be dynamic I am not able to achieve it.
Any help is appreciated

@Ksp585 : Please find below screenshot where it is calculating wrongly: After the green link next values should have been 751 (2638-3389) instead it has calculated as 3367 based on previous calculation (3389-22=3367) which is wrong:

[image]

Comment: I have even tried below also : but its giving error like "invalid after "

if([COL C] is Not NULL=, First(If([COL B]=[COL C],[COL D]),"NA")) ) OVER ([COL A, COL B, COL C , COL D]))), "NA")OVER""

Answer (score 2):

@Nischey Anand- Please try the below solution.

**Step 1:** Add 'row_id' column

```
RowId()
```

**Step 2:** Insert calculation column with the below custom expression

```
If([Column C] is not null,Sum([Column D]) over ([row_id]) - first([Column D]) over ([Column C]),[Column D])
```

**Here is the final output:**

[image]

Hope this helps!

***Answer updated based on additional details provided:***

Add a calculated column with the below custom expression.

```
If(Sum(If([Column B]=[Column C],[Column D])) over ([Column C]) is not null,[Column D] - Sum(If([Column B]=[Column C],[Column D])) over ([Column C]),[Column D])
```

**Here is the updated final output table:**

[image]

Hope this solves your question!

Comment: Logically it seems fine, but I am still getting same error "The Expression is not valid after 'over' on the line 1 character" , which is was getting earlier, This error is for the last over ie for " over ([Column C]),[Column D])
"  this part...please help

Comment: @Nischey Anand- I tested this solution in 6.0 and 7.8 versions of Spotfire and it works fine without errors. Could please capture the formula that you are entering with the error and post it in your question?

Comment: @Nischey Anand- Just a quick clarification - [Column D] at the end is not part of the over function, it is else part of the if() condition.

Comment: this part helped me in solving the issue mentioned by me earlier " [Column D] at the end is not part of the over function, it is else part of the if() condition.".... There was one bracket difference. However I observed that we have no considered the part where the condition is not considered : "such that when Col B=Col C and corresponding value of Col D has to be taken and subtracted to Col D values until next time Col B=Col C occurs."  Due to this it simply groups by Col C giving wrong calculation ....I have updated my values which I am getting in my production

Comment: @Nischey Anand- Sorry, I was little busy and couldn't get back to you sooner. I have updated my answer based on the additional details that you have provided. Hope that solves your question.